# cannot access to nature.com website

Tags: server, internet

I have a problem: since yesterday I cannot access to nature.com, it gives me "internal server error", but I know the site is working plus I can access with my phone. I really don't understand, internet is working fine, I tried to disconnect and reconnect internet, restart the pc, disable/enable the plugins, but nothing changed. Please someone help me solve this mystery....

Chiara

ps I have ubuntu 14.04, and neither chromium nor firefox are able to open the page, plus everytime I refresh the page, it gives me a different reference number.

Comment: Same for me, Chrome, Chromium and FF return "Internal server error (500)", but if i access with curl from the same machine it loads.

Comment: Yup!  Happening here too on FF!  I would write an email to the web admins...  (Lynx seems to work, which *unfortunately* makes your **question off-topic as it is not about Ubuntu**)  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby, it is about ubuntu(linux i guess), i tested on Mac and it works, changing the user agent to something not-linux it works.

Comment: @bistoco That's not a solution, that's a work-around.  **;-)** The web-site needs to be informed about this. if you do that and update your answer, I'll upvote...  **:-)**

Comment: email sent, for courtesy ( web developer here), not for the upvote ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the useragent, maybe they have rules for that.

I tested from my Mac, and it works on both Safari and FF.

Workaround , change your useragent on FF following [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/), it worked for me.